# Typescript and File Upload with JQuery Definitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm using typescript and I have a file upload form.  But my typescript is returning an error.

```
$('body').on('change', '#upload_button input[type="file"]', (evt)=>{
    let file_list = evt.target.files;
});
```

This is the error:

> Property 'files' does not exist on type 'Element'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $(...) always returns a list of elements. Get the first (and unique) one with [0], and cast it to `HTMLInputElement`.

```
$('body').find('#upload_button input[type="file"]')
    .on('change', (evt: JQuery.TriggeredEvent) => {
        let input = <HTMLInputElement>$(evt.currentTarget)[0];
        let file_list = input.files;
        //...
    });
```

Note that `files` is an member of `HTMLInputElement`

Answer (score 0):

For typescript file is not a method of the `HTMLElement` type. Trying changing your type for the element to `HTMLInputElement`

Example

`let fileInput : HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('input');`

Comment: how would this be done with jQuery?  This is the first time i have used typescript for a project, and i must say there are some really odd things that make no sense about it.

Comment: tried putting this in my code and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Property 'files' does not exist on type 'Element'` is solved for me by:

```
$('body').on('change', '#upload_button input[type="file"]', (evt)=>{
  evt.preventDefault()
  const fileInput: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector(event.currentTarget);
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  ...  
});
```